# jPlayer - confirm box after sound end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jplayer

How can I show a confirm box after sound end? I use jPlayer HTML5 Audio player to play sound. I have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function(event) {
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            mp3: "http://mysite.com/sound.mp3"
                        });
                    },
                    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js",
                    supplied: "mp3"
                });             
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`ended` event](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://mysite.com/sound.mp3"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        ended: function() {
            confirm('The sound ended?');
        }
    });             
});
```